# Need to rename an image after upload

Tags: php

i have this code here which outputs me an image.. I need to change it because for the moment it gives me something like : test.jpg, what i need is for it to give me test_s.jpg

Using the rename function i guess!

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetPath = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath);
$targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
tamano_nuevo_foto($stempFile, 420, $stargetFile);
```

Comment: You can just use something like: `$targetFile = $targetPath . 'small_'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];`

Comment: this is usually done via copy command (from temp folder to your desired target folder) with the "correct" name. if(copy($tempFile, $newpath_plus_filename))
{ // yay success }

Comment: The point is i need the name of the file and add a _s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$extension = array_pop( explode(".", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']) ); //get extension
$targetFile = $targetPath . "some_new_name".$extension;
tamano_nuevo_foto($tempFile, 420, $targetFile);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, it's the closest i can get.. but i need to save the name of the file, i just need to add a _s after the name and then the extension..can you please modify it?

Comment: I figured it out :)
You made my day, i have been struggling with this for days! not just this little part byt anyways :):)::) thanks thanks thanks!

Comment: glad you figured it out ... :)

Answer (score 0):

First: You seem to have a path that can be manipulated by the the user. Your usage of $_REQUEST['folder'] directly in your path is bad. The user could put ANYTHING in there, even stuff like ../../../ to move around your filesystem!

To change the name, simply:

$targetFile = $targetPath . "myfilename.png";

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this function:

```
function add_s($file){
    $fName = substr($file, 0,strpos($file, "."));
    $fExtension = substr($file, strpos($file, "."));
    $newFName = $fName."_s".$fExtension;
    return $newFName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php) and [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/'; // should make this more secure, like a fixed path or in a whitelist
$targetPath = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath);
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$basename = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$targetFile = $targetPath . $basename . "_s" . $ext;
move_uploaded_file ( $tempFile , string $targetFile)
//tamano_nuevo_foto($stempFile, 420, $stargetFile); // move and resize ??
```